# How can I load this select input field with options passed using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

When loading an HTML table, there is this `select` input field, which should make available some options.
Right after the `HTML` table row is built, I'm calling a function, which should populate this input field, getting it by its `class`.

Here is the `HTML` piece and the function:

```js
function loadTelaOptions(telaOptions) {
  telaOptions = ["09-Black", "11-LT Jaspe"]; //Here for tests
  document.querySelector('tableBodySelect').value = '';

  let selectList = document.querySelector('tableBodySelect');
  let options = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
  for (let i = options.length; i--;) {
    selectList.removeChild(options[i]);
  }
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = "";
  option.text = "";
  selectList.appendChild(option);
  telaOptions.forEach(function(item, index) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = item.toLowerCase();
    option.text = item;
    selectList.appendChild(option)
  });
}
```

```html
<td>
  <select name='tableselect' required='required' class='tableBodySelect' value='Trying'>
  </select>
</td>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `querySelector('tableBodySelect');` is looking for `<tableBodySelect>`. You missing the class selector. Next `for (let i = options.length; i--;) { selectList.removeChild(options[i]);` You are selecting one over the actual number of option elements since it is zero based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors for `.querySelector('tableBodySelect')` doesn't match your desired elements. You try to match the classes, therefore you need to prepend a `.` to your selector `.querySelector('.tableBodySelect')`

This does already resolve your issue.

```js
function loadTelaOptions(telaOptions) {
  telaOptions = ["09-Black", "11-LT Jaspe"]; //Here for tests
  document.querySelector('.tableBodySelect').value = '';

  let selectList = document.querySelector('.tableBodySelect');
  let options = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
  for (let i = options.length; i--;) {
    selectList.removeChild(options[i]);
  }
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = "";
  option.text = "";
  selectList.appendChild(option);
  telaOptions.forEach(function(item, index) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = item.toLowerCase();
    option.text = item;
    selectList.appendChild(option)
  });
}
loadTelaOptions();
```

```html
<td>
  <select name='tableselect' required='required' class='tableBodySelect' value='Trying'>
  </select>
</td>
```